# Error in R while trying to Plot a ScatterPlot

Tags: r, statistics, rgui

I'm trying to plot an scatter plot in R:

```
plot(cars$Hwy.MPG ~ cars$HP ,col=cars$Cyl , data=cars, pch=8)
```

and get an error:

```
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : 
  numerical color values must be >= 0, found -1
```

Cause I have values of '-1' in the column 'Cyl'  . But I need those records too , and can't drop them.. 
how could I plot it with negative numbers too?
Thanks

Comment: Well since it's going to plot with some color, you'll have to pick a valid color number to replace the -1 with (I would guess -1 represents missing data). So pick a color to represent "missing" and replace -1 with that.

Comment: Yeah... what colors *do* you want?  I recommend against using different colors purely to discriminate different data levels unless you have only a very few levels.

Comment: thanks , but Can I do that in the plot function?
or I have to remove first records with -1 , than plot the graph ,
and after that add the records with -1.

Comment: Try it and see.  Those sort of questions are very easily answered with a little experimentation. :-)

Comment: Hi , I did that with the first way (delete -1 , plot , add -1)
but it's look bad. so I want to know if there is way to plot the graph with negative values..

Comment: why not try: 
    plot(cars$Hwy.MPG ~ cars$HP ,col=1+cars$Cyl , data=cars, pch=8)